# How do I calculations on SQL aggregates?

Tags: sql

Using SQL how to multiply 2 columns in a table and add their sum divided by the sum of another column?

My table looks like this:

```
    A  |  B  | A*B 
   ----|-----|------
    1  |  2  |   2
    5  |  4  |  20
    3  |  5  |  15
```

Lets assume `C = sum(A*B)` and `D = sum(B)`. I want to calculate `C/D`.

e.g., above `C = sum(A*B) = 37` and `D = sum(B) = 11`  therefore `C/D = 3.367`

Comment: `select sum(a*b) / sum(b) from your_table` <- seriously, how lazy can one be? And who the f* upvotes this question?

Comment: please check manually the values will be diff with ur f* formula

Comment: No, they won't, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88aac/1/0

Comment: it won't work in SQL server without explicit casting. it will return 3 in sql server. but on other hand you are correct as OP did not mention the RDBMS name.

Comment: Fine, then make it `select sum(a*b) / sum(b * 1.0) from your_table`

Comment: @DeepakPawar The question does not mention specific DBMS. Some of them will cast to float or decimal, others will keep the summed values as integers and do integer division.

Comment: @fancyPants or: `select 1.0 * sum(a*b) / sum(b) from your_table;`

Answer (score 1):

This should do exactly what you want

```
SELECT (SUM(A*B)) / SUM(B) From table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT f1, f2, (f2 / f1) as result from 
(SELECT SUM(B) as f1, SUM(A*B) as f2 FROM table)
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this in SQL Server, might be helpful :

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
   A INT,
   B INT
) 

INSERT INTO @table 
VALUES
(1,2),
(5,4),
(3,5)

SELECT SUM(a * b)                                                          [A*B],
       SUM(b)                                                              [B],
       CAST(SUM(a * b) / CAST(SUM(b) AS DECIMAL(13, 3)) AS DECIMAL(13, 3)) [RESULT]
FROM   @table
```

Comment: Why aren't there any statement terminators? (`;`)

Comment: I usually do not use it... I use it only in `;with cte`

Comment: I find it highly useful when reading code, especially others'. Some more reasons: [Ladies and gentlemen, start your semi-colons!](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)

Comment: Thanks for advice, I will consider this next time.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This if use full

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Name] varchar(5), [Quality] int, [No] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Name], [Quality], [No])
VALUES
  ( 'a' ,  80 , 2),
('a',   85 , 3),
('a'  , 90 , 4),
('b'  , 85 , 2),
('b',   90,  1)

;


Declare @SumNo int,@DevideNo int,@Avg float

SET @SumNo=(SELECT SUM(Quality * No) as totalVal FROM #Table1) 
SET @DevideNo=(SELECT SUM(Quality) FROM #Table1)
SET @Avg = @SumNo/@DevideNo
PRINT @Avg
```